# Why does the OSCAR database describe Landsats fire identification as "daylight only"?

Tags: earth-observation, fire

The World Meteorological Organisation (WMO) [Observing Systems Capability Analysis and Review (OSCAR)](https://www.wmo-sat.info) Tool describes the [High-Resolution Imager (HRI)](https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/180) (which flies on Pléades-1A and -1B, among other satellites) fire fractional cover capability as limited to "daylight only".  The same for Landsats [Operational Land Imager (OLI)](https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/instruments/view/375). But fires should be visible at night, why would the fire fractional cover capability be limited to daylight observations?  Do they switch off the sensor to limit energy/bandwidth/storage or is there a more technical reason?